What is the Alt+T (cut until end of buffer) shortcut for Nano on macOS?
What is the Alt+T (cut until end of buffer) shortcut for Nano on macOS?
I was used to using this in Nano on Linux, but it just does not work in macOS.

It seems that ESC+T works OK. Similar with Undo command.
